# React cannot read properties of undefined, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component that was working fine, i decided to try and build it further by adding the `getMoves` function but the results I'm getting are not as expected.

The four `console.log()`s in the code below, at the bottom of the `getMoves` function basically show the problem i'm having.

Even though both `moves` and `monz[0]` seem to be correct in the console, `moves.monz[0]` gives the error `'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')'`

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const Teams = ({ teams }) => {
  if (!teams) {
    return null;
  }

  let monz = [];

  const [moves, setMoves] = useState([]);
  const [league, setLeague] = useState("default");

  function handleChange(e) {
    setLeague(e.target.value);
  }

  const getMoves = async () => {
    const req = await fetch(`/api/move-data/${league}`);
    const json = await req.json();
    setMoves(json);
    console.log(moves); // this works
    console.log(moves.charizard); // this works
    console.log(monz[0]); // this works - prints 'charizard'
    console.log(moves.monz[0]); // this doesn't work?! 
  };

  let pokemap = teams.slice(1).map((team, index) => (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>
      <div className="MainDiv">
        {" "}
        <div>{team[0].bout}</div>{" "}
        <div class="container">
          <br />
          {Array.isArray(team) &&
            team.slice(1).map((pokemon) => (
              <React.Fragment key={pokemon.pokemon}>
                <div class="child">
                  <img src={pokemon.sprite} />
                  <div style={{ display: "none" }}>
                    {monz.push(pokemon.pokemon.toLowerCase())}
                  </div>
                  <p>{pokemon.pokemon}</p>
                </div>
              </React.Fragment>
            ))}
        </div>
        <div>
          {team[0].wins && "Score: "} <br />{" "}
          {team[0].wins && team[0].wins + "-"}
          {team[0].wins && 3 - team[0].wins}
        </div>
        <select value={league} onChange={handleChange}>
          <option value="default" selected disabled hidden>
            Pick a league
          </option>
          <option value="Great">Great</option>
          <option value="Ultra">Ultra</option>
          <option value="Master">Master</option>
          <option value="Field">Field</option>
        </select>
        <button onClick={getMoves}>Click</button>
        {/* {moves.monz[0].Name} - this doesn't work */}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  ));
  if (!teams[0]) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="bold">Win Rate: {teams[0].winrate}%</div>
      <div>{pokemap}</div>{" "}
    </>
  );
};

export default Teams;
```

Comment: Kindly share the format of your moves array

Comment: You want `moves[monz[0]]`, see [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable). `moves.monz` looks for a property called `monz` on `moves`, exactly like `moves.charizard` looks for a `charizard` property on it. If you want to use the **value** of `monz[0]` as a property key, you need to use `[]`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks this was the answer ... *facepalm* ofc it had to be something so simple. Hah. thanks again!